# Curved lines in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Doing a project in information visualization and wants to draw multiple lines from airport to airport.

Managed to get it working with great arcs, but since there is multiple flights to and from the same airport, I want to have different radiuses on the lines. Is this possible in d3?

EDIT: Here is the current code:

```
this.formatedflightdata = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: formatFlightData(this.flightdata)};

console.log(this.formatedflightdata);

var line = this.g.selectAll(".arc") 
 .data(this.formatedflightdata.features);

  line.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("opacity", "1")
    .attr("d", this.path)
    .on("click",  function(d) {
      console.log("Clicked line!")
    });

function formatFlightData(array) {
    var data = [];
    array.map(function (d, i) {
      var feature = {
        "type":       "Feature",
        "geometry":   {
          "type":        "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [d.origlong, d.origlat],
            [d.destlong, d.destlat]]
        },
        "properties": {
          "origin": d.ORIGIN,
          "destination": d.DEST,
          "dayOfMonth": d.DAY_OF_MONTH,
          "flightDate": d.FL_DATE,
          "carrier": d.CARRIER,
          "distance": d.DISTANCE
        }
      };
      data.push(feature);
    });
    return data;
  }
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2cfV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This is more of a "raw" svg question than a d3 question.
d3 is creating an svg `path` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths for more info.

Basically, you can construct your `path` to have any type of curve that you like. Specific to your example, you may ? want to insert additional elements to the array representing control points. Then, in the `.attr("d",` portion, construct strings with the appropriate curves.

Untested example:

`attr("d", this.path[0] + ""Q 12 17 " + this.path[1])`

The "Q 12 17" is trying to make a quadratic curve, with (12,17) as an arbitrarily chosen control point.

Comment: Thats not working for me unfortunately. Changed the code slightly to create single svg elements for each path. Do you know how to manipulate the already drawn svg line?